# Nmap NSE Password Brute Force is Stopping on First Positive Instance

Tags: nmap, telnet

I'm running an Nmap brute force against metasploitable2 (telnet). The script is stopping on the first found username/password and is not iterating through the entire user/password file i have provided. I have tried using all appropriate args but no luck. Any ideas?

`nmap -vv -p 23 --script telnet-brute --script-args userdb=users.txt,passdb=pw.txt --script-args telnet-brute.emptypass=true --script-args telnet-brute.firstonly=false TARGETIP`

Comment: Could you try it this way and report back? `nmap -p 23 --script telnet-brute --script-args userdb=users.txt,passdb=pw.txt,brute.emptypass=true,brute.firstonly=false <targetip>`

Comment: i think it's because any instance of firstonly causes the condition to be true. just leave it out. the default is to keep bruting

Comment: @duckcake use `@username` to address people - they will get a notification when you do that

Comment: @GreatSeaSpider for some reason your command didn't return any positive results, even though the correct words were in the respective files.

Comment: @atdre This is what i tried initially, but it didn't work, which is why i included the telnet-brute.firstonly=false arg.

Comment: You could also try adding the debug option (-d) which might assist you in understanding what's going on. You can specify it multiple times just like -v, or you can set a level using 1-9 like this: `-d4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found. --script-args can only be called once, contrary to the documentation at: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/telnet-brute.html.

The successful command is:
`nmap -d -vv -p 23 --script telnet-brute --script-args "userdb=users.txt,passdb=pass.txt,telnet-brute.emptypass=true,telnet-brute.firstonly=false" TARGETIP`

Thanks for your help @GreatSeaSpider, @atdre, @schroeder

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Fixed the documentation in r35530, should propagate to the web docs shortly.

Comment: Also want to point out: `--script-args-file` is a handy way to deal with long or complicated arguments, especially since it removes the need to quote stuff for the shell and lets you use newlines instead of commas to separate args.

Comment: awesome, trying `--script-args-file` now.

Comment: @bonsaiviking. I think may have found another issue. The args are all being passed correctly but telnet-brute is only brute forcing the first 2 correct instances. Is there a way of making it brute force all instances?

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that. Are you using Nmap 7.01? telnet-brute got an overhaul recently. If so, we can take a look at your logs with -d3 --script-trace to determine the reason. #nmap on freenode IRC or dev@nmap.org

Comment: Sorry @bonsaiviking. My mistake, it's bruting all instances correctly now using `--script-args "userdb=users.txt,passdb=pass.txt,telnet-brute.emptypass=true,telnet-brute.firstonly=false"` Yes, i'm using Nmap 7.01.